# Why do some PDFs have such ugly fonts in Document Viewer?

Tags: fonts, pdf, evince, antialiasing

Why are the fonts in Document Viewer so ugly and non-antialiased?

[image]

Comment: could you perhaps give a link to a sample file?  The fonts look fine in my pdfs.

Comment: http://coecsl.ece.illinois.edu/ge423/datasheets/segway/smoother-based-d-attitude.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you see this behavior only for some documents, right?

In that case I think that you see output from an old LaTeX version with standard LaTeX bitmap fonts. I have found the document that you are showing and the fonts are non-aliased also on my system -- although I know that regular documents look perfect. It's also non-aliased under Windows, so there.

Comment: You're exactly right. The DVI-to-PDF conversion was done improperly.

Comment: Oh, so I can't help it seems. Well, we'll live through it - with a cold beer in hand the fonts doesn't really matter.

Comment: If you print it, it will look "normal".

Answer (score 0):

There is no text in your pdf file, but a compressed jpeg image for each page.

So the font cannot scale. It is a fixed picture, not a scalable font.

Comment: Nah, there is text alright: http://www-robotics.usc.edu/~stergios/icra99-3D-final.pdf. It's just that it doesn't use vector fonts.

Comment: The main font is of poor Quality... it is a type 3 font. Type 3 Fonts are bitmap fonts -> same problem like with other "pictures" they are not scalable.

Comment: @mondjunge: Type 3 fonts are not _of_ _poor_ _quality_. They are simply not optimized for low resolution devices like screens.

Comment: What Martin said. Your answer is incorrect in that there is no "compressed image for each page", JPEG or otherwise.

Comment: You are correct, the first time I downloaded the pdf it was copy protected, so I could not highlight any chars, so I thought it was a jpeg...